# How to not display the pearson's coefficient on seaborn's jointplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, kernel-density

I'm trying to generate a joint plot from the seaborn library, and I was wondering whether anyone knew how to not display the pearson's coefficient on the plot as it seems to be the default, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLUHO.png):

[image]

The code that I'm using the generate the plot is shown below;

```
g = sns.jointplot(x=pdf['embedding 1'], y=pdf['embedding 2'], 
              data=pdf, kind="kde", color="m")
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="w", s=0.1, marker="o")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: Updating to seaborn version 0.9.0 made it work (I was running version 0.8.1)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, I just checked and I'm currently running version 0.8.1, I will try updating it

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not sure what the case was then, but updating my 0.8.1 to 0.9.0 did the trick - thank you!

Comment: Anyone know how to SHOW the pearson / p-value with seaborn 0.9 other than calculating it and annotating it manually on a plot?

Comment: @Tetlanesh with g.annotate(stats.pearsonr) you can change it for any other func

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure whether your problem was fixed by upgrading to 0.9.0 as per your comment, but I also don't think the legend would magically disappear when doing the upgrade.

To remove the pearson's coefficient, add:

```
g.ax_joint.legend_.remove()
```

before `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem with seaborn version 0.9.0
I couldn't understand the reason but I sold the problem with adding **pearsonr score** to the plot by;

```
import scipy.stats as stats
g.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
plt.show()
```